# Unwrapping optionals to a pre-defined variable in the guard condition without creating a new constant

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

The Swift guard statement allows you to unwrap optionals to a new constant and do an early return if the assignment fails.

```
var someString:String? = "hello"
...
...  
guard let newString = someString 
   else {
     return
   }

...
```

If I want to unwrap an optional and set it to a pre-defined non-optional variable, I've been first unwrapping to the new constant (newString) and then setting the non-optional variable after the guard statement like this:

```
var someString:String? = "hello"
var nonOptionalString:String = "bonjour"
...
...
guard let newString = someString 
   else {
     return
   }
nonOptionalString = newString

...
```

**Is there a way to set a pre-defined, non-optional var within the condition of the guard statement without creating a new constant?**  Something like the following (which doesn't work)?

```
var someString:String? = "hello"
var nonOptionalString:String = "bonjour"
...
...
guard nonOptionalString = someString 
   else {
     return
   }
...
```

If something like this isn't possible, is there an underlying philosophy behind the Swift language design or technical reason as to why this doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just test for `nil` and then force unwrap when I know it's not:

```
var someString: String? = "hello"
let nonOptionalString: String       // note, you don't have to initialize this with some bogus value

guard someString != nil else { return }
nonOptionalString = someString!
```

Or if `someString` was a parameter to some method or closure, you can unwrap in the `guard` statement using the same variable name, simplifying life even more:

```
func foo(someString: String?) {
    guard let someString = someString else { return }

    // now I can just use local `someString`, which is not optional anymore
}
```

If you're desperate to unwrap and exit-if-`nil` in a single statement, you could theoretically write a function to unwrap if it can or throw an error if it can't:

```
extension Optional {
    enum OptionalError: Error {
        case unwrapFailed
    }

    func unwrap<T>() throws -> T {
        if self == nil { throw OptionalError.unwrapFailed }
        return self as! T
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
do {
    firstNonOptional  = try firstOptional.unwrap()
    secondNonOptional = try secondOptional.unwrap()
    thirdNonOptional  = try thirdOptional.unwrap()
} catch {
    return
}
```

I think that's horrible overkill, but if you're desperate to distill it down to one line per unwrap, that's one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I would go around doing this.

1. `guard let someString = someString else { return }`

This just checks the value, with the same variable name.

2. `guard someString != nil else { return }`

Doing this second one, you can even declare it with a bang(!) it will be "pre-defined" to a "non-optional" in a way.

So now you could declare it like:

```
var someString:String! = "hello"
```

I think you are looking for exactly this.

EDIT: And now you can use your own example.

```
guard someString != nil, nonOptional == someString else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the point is to make the assignment only if the assignment is possible, write:

```
nonOptionalString = someString ?? nonOptionalString
```

If you really *also* need the `return` if the assignment is impossible, then just write an if/else clause:

```
if someString != nil {
    nonOptionalString = someString!
} else {
    return
}
```

In other words, stop trying to be so fancy and just say what you mean.